# when i create opportunity i want to update noof opportunites count and amount fields in account object using MAP+SET+LIST IN CLASS

Tags: apex, map

WHEN I TRYING TO INSERT OPPORTUNITY IT SHOWS ERROR LIKE THIS,WHERE DID I MAKE MISTAKE....

```
Apex trigger otherobj1 caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: otherobj1: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Class.OPTYROLLHANDLER.afterInsert: line 27, column 1
```

TRIGGER:

```
trigger otherobj1 on Opportunity (after insert,after delete) {
if(trigger.isInsert){
    optyrollhandler.afterInsert(trigger.new);
}else{
    optyrollhandler.afterDelete(trigger.old);
}}
```

......................................

Comment: Is there a reason you're using this type of method rather than standard rollup summary fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can use rollup summary field.So you can avoid coding

But still I had written the code snippet for your understanding:

I have rollup the Opportunity amount in account level.

Consider Account linked to many Oppportunities.(1 to Many)

steps: 
        **Using map: I will construct map with related Opportunities amount.**

```
   map<id,decimal> oppMap=new map<id,decimal>();
```

Step2: **I will just update the account with related amount**

Please check this code snipets:

```
   map<id,decimal> oppMap=new map<id,decimal>();
   for(Opportunity op:trigger.new){
     if(!oppMap.containskey(op.AccountId){
   oppMap.put(op.AccountId,oppMap.get(op.AccountId)+op.Amount); 
}
  else{
    oppMap.put(op.AccountId,op.Amount);
 }
  List<Account> acList=new List<Account>();
 for(account ac:[select id,amount from account where id in:oppMap.keyset()){
  if(ac.amount==null){
  ac.amount=oppMap.get(ac.Id);
   }
  else{
 ac.amount=ac.amount+oppMap.get(ac.Id);
   }
   acList.add(ac);
 }
  if(!acList.isEmpty()){
   update acList;
  }
```

Note:

> You can use relationship queries also for this logic

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you highlighted where the original issue was and how it's fixed. A code dump is better when accompanied with a detailed explanation.

Comment: when i try ur code it shows  System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object.how to resove this?